# Facebook CurlException: 6: Couldn't resolve host 'graph.facebook.com'

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Any one knows about this message ("CurlException: 6: Couldn't resolve host 'graph.facebook.com'") when you are trying to get "$facebook->getUser()" or $facebook->api('/me'); I really appreciated your help

Answer (score 5):

Had the same case in my environment - restarting the virtual server / the ntpd service did not solve the issue

Only when I restarted the host machine did this error go away

Comment: I did the same. Restarting the server, resolved the issue.

Comment: I also tried this and it worked temporarily and then happened again.

Answer (score 2):

Your server must not be able to resolve graph.facebook.com - is your production environment behind a Firewall or does it have misconfigured DNS?

Comment: @lgy There is a dns (opendns) but i don't know if there are some problem with that.

Answer (score 2):

I was receiving this error on my local dev server, and turns out that I needed to just reboot the operating system.

In my case, I'm using a bridged network connection.  If the internet connection is changed or disabled at all on the host operating system while using the dev server, something gets altered with the DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Your host is most likely blocking outgoing connections. If you can ssh to the server try pinging graph.facebook.com and see if you can reach that server from your server. If you don't have ssh access to the server you could try using php exec or system to run the ping command.

It also may be due to your host not allowing urls to be opened within php or not allowing SSL.

Check this search for more ideas from the facebook dev forums: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?ix=seb&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Couldn%27t+resolve+host+%27graph.facebook.com#hl=en&q=+site%3aforum.developers.facebook.net+Couldn%27t+resolve+host+%27graph.facebook.com&sa=X&ei=EchfT-7vJ8WyiQKN7oW2BA&ved=0CDEQrQIwAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=562bdbc5a3885de6&biw=1680&bih=922&ix=seb)

Comment: i have a local server but it is the first time that this happend. I don't know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by setting FacebookCurlHttpClient.php line 104:

`CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE => CURL_IPRESOLVE_V6`

You should not have to edit the PHP-SDK code and just do this in your code:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([...]);
$fb->getClient()->getHttpClientHandler()->facebookCurl->setopt(CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V6);
```

But the `FacebookHttpClientInterface` only exposes the `send` method (and the `facebookCurl` member variable is protected), so that's not possible.