# Facebook PHP API returns error "Couldn't resolve host"

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook JavaScript API is working and able to read, but the PHP API returns this error.

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught CurlException: 6: Couldn't resolve host 'graph.facebook.com'
> thrown in **/home/domain.com/public_html/facebook-php/src/base_facebook.php** on line **994**

The line 994 is this:

> ```
>   $e = new FacebookApiException(array(
>     'error_code' => curl_errno($ch),
>     'error' => array(
>     'message' => curl_error($ch),
>     'type' => 'CurlException',
>     ),
>   ));
>   curl_close($ch);
>   throw $e;
> ```

What might be the issue? I have opened the port 25, https etc.

Comment: Did [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692811/facebook-curlexception-6-couldnt-resolve-host-graph-facebook-com) help ?

Answer (score 0):

`Couldn't resolve host ....` indicates a server configuration issue. I handle DNS server for my company and this particular error is basically saying your host is unable to lookup the ip address for graph.facebook.com domain. Check with your host to see if they've made any changes recently. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is it because of opening and closing of ports?

Comment: Have you checked the host's URL? Does that matches to FB API? Sometimes this could be a problem. Please DO NOT share the host url here in the comment but just check what I said.

Comment: Also, it would help if you could catch that exception by using PHP's try and catch block. for example: try { something ....} catch (FacebookApiException $e) { 
    print_r($e);
}

Comment: This is the first part that i got: FacebookApiException Object ( [result:protected] => Array ( [error_code] => 6 [error] => Array ( [message] => Couldn't resolve host 'graph.facebook.com' [type] => CurlException ) ) [message:protected] => Couldn't resolve host 'graph.facebook.com' [string:private] => [code:protected] => 6

Comment: I think the server disallows outgoing connections which is something your hosting provider needs to look at. This error means something on your server prevents your site from connecting to Facebook.com. I am totally exhausted here but tried my best. If you do get answer please share with us.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the `Couldn't resolve host 'graph.facebook.com'` error. In my code the exception was being captured with:

```
...
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    die(errorReplacement("Error 002: " . $e->getMessage()));
}
```

I resolved the issue by checking the [Facebook Developer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) website to find out my Graph API was no longer supported. `v2.2` is no longer supported so I changed:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'MY_APP_ID',
    'app_secret' => 'MY_APP_SECRET',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);
```

to:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'MY_APP_ID',
    'app_secret' => 'MY_APP_SECRET',
]);
```